# Mutating an array within a view from a subview "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm attempting to call a function in a struct (swiftui view) which appends an item to an array that is then mapped to a list.   The function is being called in a subview, but I keep getting the error "Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable".

Heres the function in the parent:

```
mutating func addNote(note: String){
        var newNotes = notes;
        newNotes.append(note);
        notes = newNotes;
    }
```

Inside the body has:

```
List {
      ForEach(notes, id: \.self) { string in
             Section(header: Text("1/22/20")){
                 Text(string)
             }
       }...
```

To pass the function to the subview i try this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: AddNoteView(delegate: addNote)) {
            Text("Add note")
}
```

and my addNoteView() looks like this:

```
struct AddNoteView : View {
    @State var note: String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    var delegate: (String) -> ()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Note")){
                    TextField("Note", text:$note)
                }
                Section(){
                    Button(action: {
                            delegate(note)
                            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()}){
                       Text("Add note")

                    }
```

Anyone having any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can not append an item with a struct. Make your array with @State var newNotes...... or use class for operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI view is struct you cannot mutate it from within self. Make `notes` as `@State` then you can use

```
    @State var notes: [String] = []

    // .. other code

    func addNote(note: String) {
        notes.append(note)
    }
```